# foreach fills from bottom to top

Tags: c#, winforms, search, controls

My foreach goes the wrong way. It's now setting the template from bottom to top but this needs to go in opposite order

I have added a printscreen to make it clear:

[image: Wrong order]

The only solution I know is to select them 1 by 1 by name and then set the right answer, but how will I accomplice this? Or is there still a way to let the `foreach` go in the right "direction"

this is the foreach I'm using:

```
var labels = this.Controls
    .OfType<Label>()
    .Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("answer_"));

int x = 1;
foreach (Label l in labels)
{
    int y = x * tafel;
    l.Text = y.ToString();
    x++;
}
```

Comment: I never assume any order with a foreach loop, you need to identify you are using the correct label inside the foreach. The order that they are in depends a lot on how you made the form in this case. They may be in the order you have them in the designer, by Z order, or by chance, and you can't assume its always backwards. Use the .Tag property of the control or verify you have the right one some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure they are always in exact reverse order you can always add `.Reverse()` to your `this.Controls.OfType<Label>...` queries. A little bit ugly and hack IMHO but should work.

A less kludgy solution would be to add an `.OrderBy()` to make them appear in the order you want them to appear. For Example:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>().OrderBy(l=>l.Text)
```

You can also use `.OrderByDescending()` or use an overload of `OrderBy` with a custom `Comparer<Label>` class.

Comment: the `OrderBy()` looks interesting. Could you give an example? (sorry, I'm new with c#)